# call to a function that inside another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function that is **in** another function.

*example for the functions:*

```
function funcOne() {
     function funcTwo() {    // i want to call to this function
         //do something
     }
}
```

I need to call to `funcTwo` function, when I click on a button which is **outside** of these two functions

how can i do it?

Comment: You don't. That's how lexical scoping works. You'll have to restructure your code.

Comment: What he said, why dont you ask what you actually want to do?

Comment: @Fonzy couse that what i need. but ok, i will restructure my source.

Comment: The general consensus, is you can't nest functions like that.

Answer (score 2):

No, You can't call unless you return that function.

Function2 is private to function1.

you use

```
function funcOne() {
    return {
     funcTwo :function() {    // i want to call to this function
         //do something
     }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** Structuring code

```
function funcOne() {
   var funcTwo = function() {    // private function
        //do something
     }
    return {
      funcTwo : funcTwo      
   }
}
```

Now you can call it as:

```
funcOne().funcTwo()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have it defined in your example, you can't. `funcTwo` is scoped inside of `funcOne`, so it can only be called from inside `funcOne`. You can assign `funcTwo` to a variable that is scoped outside of `funcOne` and that would work:

```
var funcRef;
function funcOne() {
    funcRef = function funcTwo() {

    }
}
```

In this case, `funcRef` would hold a reference and could be used, but that reference is only set once `funcOne` has been executed.

Answer (score 1):

Reading some [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) may help you understand...

Try recoding as:

```
function funcOne() {
   this.funcTwo = function() {
   }
}
```

I think you'd have to declare an instance of a funcOne object and then call the funcTwo method of that object. I'm a bit busy at the moment so I can't refine this answer at the moment.

Comment: +1 for this! I was reading continuous pop-up of answers but no one thought about creating a simple constructor....to add...for OP....all he needs to do is ..var f= new funcone(); f.funcTwo()//whatever

Comment: i think that its what i need. but how can i call to funcTwo? <code>funcOne().funcTwo();</code>?

Comment: This actually is.. horrible. You'd hope that `funcOne` gets executed in the global scope and therefore, write to the global scope by accessing `this`. Never ever do that.

Comment: @jAndy: Can you care to explain little more, please?

Comment: Who am I to argue with a method proposed by a giant in the field of  JavaScript? :-)

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades the problem is `this`. Its never a stable or reliable value. If you call `funcOne` with lets say `.call()` or `.apply()` it would break. Also if the code runs in *strict mode* it would break because it would set `this` to `undefined`.

In a very optimistic environment, `this` would reference the global scope (`window`) and hence, we would write `window.funcTwo =` so its "accessible" afterwards from everywhere.

Comment: In this case you're treating funcOne as an object, so the problems you mention won't occur. See the last couple of sentences of my answer...

Comment: @jAndy: I still can't understand why those problems happen when you create a new object using functone. Now we will be basically creating an object from functone and "this" will evaluate to the new object itself. How it can break your code? Yes, I understand when you use with call or bind, "this" in this case can evaluate to window object but in this context, I think you are being extra skeptical. Please, let me tell you, I am not trying to argue with you...I am learning javascript nowadays with David Flannagan book and I am trying to know something more from gurus like you.

Comment: Of course, if you would create an instance by calling `new funcOne()` it would be a different story. But then you need to access `funcTwo` in a different way, like `new funcOne().funcTwo();`. Gnah, nevermind :-)

Comment: Crockford himself states that if a function is intended to be called as a constructor (using "new") then the name of that function should be capitalized, to make sure that callers avoid the problems @jAndy mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as the second function will be created just when the first function is called. it is not existent prior to that.

You would have to define it outside the first function like so:

```
function funcOne() {

}
function funcTwo() {    // i want to call to this function
    //do something
}
```

Or you could also call the first function and return the second function like this:

```
function funcOne() {
     function funcTwo() {    // i want to call to this function
         //do something
     }
     return functTwo;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var f = funcOne();
f();
```